# [RAILS][Javascript] Is it "clean" to use controller variables in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm having a little question about convention and bests ways of doing things in rails.

Right now for a view I need to get an array of hash that I can construct way easier in my controller. I need this arry for my javascript code...

So I far i found a solution that isn't an ajax request which is this one :

```
var toto = #{@controller_var.to_json}
```

I know that it's probably "better" of doing an ajax request or to store this variable in erb code... But I try to limit myself to do ajax requests (since this page already does a few ones) and I dislike creating hidden field to store my controller method...

Anyway, if you could give your opinion/advices on this I would really apreciate it ! :)

Best regards !

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast how about railscasts approach ? not much has changed in passing values to your javascript I think ...Also , beware of putting the line you wrote in a javascript file due to asset compilation .

Comment: I did not quite get your last idea... So far my line is in my html (haml actually) file... From I saw somewhere else, i understand that if I put this sort of code in it's own JS file it will not work anymore because JS and Rails do not communicate the way Rails and Html files does...

Comment: What you're doing (putting it in html/haml) is OK . putting it in a js file is no good due to assets precompilation , but you seem to be doing it right.

Comment: Alright, many thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary problem with this approach is that your javascript is now tightly coupled with rails and it can not be tested in isolation without a full rails server running.

I totally avoid server generated javascript for this reason.

Even if you don't go the full way and build an API driven client application, the least you can do is to inject the JSON in a dom element:

```
<script id="toto" type="application/json">
  <%= @controller_var.to_json %>
</script>
```

Now in your test cases you can use a static HTML page where the script can contain mock data.

Another problem is that you can not serve server generated javascript through a CDN. This is not a problem if your js responses are very small but now to interact with the javascript existing on the page you will most likely resort to global variables.

Besides the obvious issues with global variables leading to less maintainable code, the extent to which minifiers and optimizers can perform dead code elimination suffers significantly.

Comment: I get your comment and thank you for it. But personally I do not expect testing my JS out of my Rails environment... With that in mind, do you still think my choice is not the best one ? :) By the way, I'm not trying to get over some culpability or such ;)

Comment: I have updated my answer with additional arguments. Please take a look at the last 2 paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you very much, I could totally apply your arguments with my current situation, it is a great help ! :D